# Missing something simple in getting mvc route to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It's late, I've had a lot happen today and I must be missing something very simple.

I have a route such as this:

```
routes.MapRoute("RequestKey", "License/RequestKey/{apello}/{requestcipher}",
             new { controller = "ProductKey", action = "RequestKey" },
             new { apello = "", requestcipher = "" },
             new[] { "....Controllers" }
```

My controller action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public string RequestKey(string apello, string requestcipher)
{
   return "Yeah";
}
```

And the url doesn't hit the controller action....time for bed?

```
http://localhost:53764/License/RequestKey/qwerqewrqwr/zxcvzcvzcx
```

Comment: Remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute!

Comment: OK...yeah very dumb. Calling directly with ChildOnly decoration not going to work....don't I need to decorate with HttpPost thought?

Comment: Looks like its a GET, so you would not decorate it with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke...your point was definitely valid but interestingly the route didn't like the parms = "". When I switched it to UrlParm.optional it came to life.

Comment: Dont understand? I didn't mention anything about parms?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I removed the ChildActionOnly decoration because that was definitely wrong. However it was still not working so based upon @mikeng I removed all params. It worked. Added them back as param = "" and it stopped. So then I switched the params to .Optional and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags indicate that you are using `ASP.NET MVC 4`, then try this route mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you have the possibility to upgrade to `ASP.NET MVC 5` then you can use `Attribute routing` and you should then have the possibility to write custom routes next to your Controller Action methods like this..

```
[Route("License/RequestKey/{apello}/{requestcipher}")]
public string RequestKey(string apello, string requestcipher)
{
    return "Yeah";
}
```

Comment: Plus one for the sweet taste of MVC 5....can't go there yet but looking forward to it....oh yeah as I mentioned above switching the parms from parm = "" to param1 = UrlParameter.Optional made the difference as it is now working.